# Generating a case switch for every row in db

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I'm generating a case for a switch in js for every row not empty in my db. For every case I'm generating a new option:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function dropdownlist(listindex)
{
    document.formname.subcategory.options.length = 0;

    switch (listindex)
    {
        <?php $stmt = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `filters` WHERE `primary_category` <> '' "); ?> 
        <?php while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) { ?>
          case "<?php echo $row['primary_category']; ?>" :
                <?php $stmt2 = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `filters` WHERE `second_category` <> '' "); ?>
                <?php $i= 0; ?>
                <?php while ($row2 = $stmt2->fetch()) { ?>
                    <?php if($i === count($row2)) { ?>

                       break;

                    <?php } else { ?>
                        document.formname.subcategory.options[<?php echo $i;?>]=new Option("<?php echo $row2['second_category']; ?>","value1.1")
                        <?php $i++; ?>
                    <?php } ?>



                <?php }?>
            <?php  }?>

          default:
              document.formname.subcategory.options[0]=new Option("Select Category")
              break;
      }
      return true;
      }
</script>
```

For some reason, one second category is not shown , maybe the break happens to quickly. This is how it looks:

[image]

Inside my db there is one more :
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: The whole purpuse is to give the user the option to choose for every category a sub cutegory.

The html for those Category and Sub-Category is here :

```
<table width="50%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
    <tr>
        <td>Category:</td>
        <td width="59%" align="left" valign="middle"><select name="category" id="category" onchange="dropdownlist(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">

        <option class="hidden"  selected disabled value="">Select Category</option>
        <!-- Generate categories -->

        <?php $stmt = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `filters` WHERE `primary_category` <> '' "); ?>
          <?php while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) { ?>
            <option class = "form-control" name ="primary_category"><?php echo $row['primary_category']; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td >Sub Category:</td>
        <td align="left" valign="middle"><script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
        document.write('<select name="subcategory"><option value="">Select Sub-Category</option></select>')
        </script>
        <noscript><select name="subcategory" id="subcategory" >
        <option class ="hiden" selected disabled value="">Select Sub-Category</option>
        </select>
        </noscript></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: _“What am I doing wrong?”_ - you start with “I am creating a switch”, without even giving a proper explanation of what the purpose of the whole thing is to begin with. Explain what you want to _achieve_ here, based on what kind of input data, first of all.

Comment: That code is incredibly confusing.  Why are you mixing PHP and JavaScript like that?  Why not just build the dropdown element entirely in PHP/HTML?

Comment: Does the first item have a secondary category?

Comment: This might be the most elaborate way of building a dropdown from a database table I've ever seen. It's got *everything*. I'd suggest taking a step back from this, it's no wonder you're having trouble finding the issue. You might want to look into just building up some JSON data from your DB results, and then querying that *separately* in your Javascript. Try and do one thing at once.